# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Could not start a new session. Response code 500 error using Appium Java

Tags: java, build.gradle, appium-android, gui-testing, selenium-java

I am still very new to UI test automation.
When I run the code up to line 27 ("String session ID..."), my APK starts on the emulator and my Appium server also runs smoothly.
Now when I want to run a Simple UI test, I get the following error message:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 404. Message: The session identified by 72bf293f-5423-4430-b126-96be60d37a2c is not known
> ```

Code:

```
package setup;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class CapabilityBase {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

        DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,"android");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "12");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Pixel");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "uiautomator2");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "/Users/firstname.lastname/eclipse-workspace/BMUI_testAutomation/src/test/resources/SystemUnderTest/app-staging.apk");

        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");

        AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(url, desiredCapabilities);
        String sessionId = driver.getSessionId().toString();

        //driver.findElement(By.id("com.google.android.permissioncontroller/com.android.permissioncontroller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity/permission_allow_button")).click();

        driver.findElement (new By.ByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'Your Login']")).click();
        //driver.findElement (new By.ByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'Your Login']")).sendKeys("02209");
        //driver.findElement (new By.ByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'Your PIN']")).click();
        //driver.findElement (new By.ByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'Your PIN']")).sendKeys("030378");

// System.out.print("test passed");


    }
}
```

Error:

````
    Executing ':CapabilityBase.main()'...
    
    > Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
    > Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
    > Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
    > Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
    
    > Task :CapabilityBase.main()
    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 404. Message: The session identified by 72bf293f-5423-4430-b126-96be60d37a2c is not known 
    Host info: host: 'MBPvonEnrico2', ip: '2a02:8109:9f80:1a68:0:0:0:ea6f%en0'
    Build info: version: '4.7.1', revision: 'c6795baf1a3'
    System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.16', java.version: '1.8.0_292'
    Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
    Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[{appium:app=/Users/enrico.weck/eclipse-workspace/BMUI_testAutomation/src/test/resources/SystemUnderTest/app-staging.apk, appium:autoGrantPermissions=true, appium:automationName=uiautomator2, appium:deviceName=Pixel, platformName=ANDROID, appium:platformVersion=12}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {app: /Users/enrico.weck/eclipse-..., autoGrantPermissions: true, automationName: uiautomator2, deviceName: Pixel, platformName: ANDROID, platformVersion: 12}}]
    Capabilities {}
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:148)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:133)
        at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumProtocolHandshake.createSession(AppiumProtocolHandshake.java:102)
        at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:194)
        at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:262)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:551)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:229)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:159)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:80)
        at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:92)
        at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:117)
        at setup.CapabilityBase.main(CapabilityBase.java:26)
    
    > Task :CapabilityBase.main() FAILED
    
    Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
    
    You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
    
    See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
    3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date
    
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':CapabilityBase.main()'.
    > Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    
    * Try:
    > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
    > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    > Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    BUILD FAILED in 27s
    ```
````

Server Logs:

```
    
        [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 200 29274 ms - 1106
        [HTTP] 
        [HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/8e481bd0-d86d-4310-aac1-d0dcebe57e76/element
        [HTTP] {"using":"xpath","value":"//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'Your Login']"}
        [W3C (8e481bd0)] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["xpath","//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'Your Login']","8e481bd0-d86d-4310-aac1-d0dcebe57e76"]
        [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, css selector, -android uiautomator
        [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
        [WD Proxy] Matched '/element' to command name 'findElement'
        [WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /element] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8202/wd/hub/session/0a905b04-4358-45e9-ba42-c3e8ec736cee/element] with body: {"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'Your Login']","context":"","multiple":false}
        [WD Proxy] Got response with status 400: {"sessionId":"0a905b04-4358-45e9-ba42-c3e8ec736cee","value":{"error":"invalid selector","message":"org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.XPathParserException: CUP parser error: Parser error: line 1 col 54: ]","stacktrace":"io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.XPathParserException: CUP parser error: Parser error: line 1 col 54: ]\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.core.AccessibilityNodeInfoDumper.findNodes(AccessibilityNodeInfoDumper.java:213)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.utils.ElementLocationHelpers.getXPathNodeMatch(ElementLocationHelpers.java:119)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.FindElement.findElement(FindElement.java:88)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.FindElement.safeHandle(FindElement.java:67)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.SafeRequestHandler.handle(SafeRequestHandler.java:59)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleRequest(AppiumServlet.java:266)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handl...
        [W3C] Matched W3C error code 'invalid selector' to InvalidSelectorError
        [W3C (8e481bd0)] Encountered internal error running command: io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.XPathParserException: CUP parser error: Parser error: line 1 col 54: ]
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.appium.uiautomator2.core.AccessibilityNodeInfoDumper.findNodes(AccessibilityNodeInfoDumper.java:213)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.appium.uiautomator2.utils.ElementLocationHelpers.getXPathNodeMatch(ElementLocationHelpers.java:119)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.FindElement.findElement(FindElement.java:88)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.FindElement.safeHandle(FindElement.java:67)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.SafeRequestHandler.handle(SafeRequestHandler.java:59)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleRequest(AppiumServlet.java:266)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleHttpRequest(AppiumServlet.java:260)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.appium.uiautomator2.http.ServerHandler.channelRead(ServerHandler.java:68)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:435)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:250)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:611)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:552)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:466)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)] Caused by: org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.XPathParserException: CUP parser error: Parser error: line 1 col 54: ]
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.internal.InternalXPathParser.parse(InternalXPathParser.java:67)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.JFlexCupParser.parse(JFlexCupParser.java:33)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.Engine.parseExpression(Engine.java:17)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at io.appium.uiautomator2.core.AccessibilityNodeInfoDumper.findNodes(AccessibilityNodeInfoDumper.java:211)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    ... 37 more
        [W3C (8e481bd0)] Caused by: org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.internal.CupError
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.internal.XPathCup.report_error(XPathCup.java:3238)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at java_cup.runtime.lr_parser.syntax_error(lr_parser.java:396)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at java_cup.runtime.lr_parser.parse(lr_parser.java:595)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.internal.InternalXPathParser.parse(InternalXPathParser.java:47)
        [W3C (8e481bd0)]    ... 40 more
        [W3C (8e481bd0)] 
        [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/8e481bd0-d86d-4310-aac1-d0dcebe57e76/element 400 1414 ms - 5068
```

I have already tried a few things as well as a JDK or appium upgrade or changing the runner to intellij. Maybe someone can help me thx.

Comment: Share the Appium server logs please. Also, what's the Appium server version?

Comment: Hey @OmprakashChavan, sorry for the late answer, my current appium version is 1.22.3, I've inserted the server logs above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the way you are using the selector is not correct.

Please change this statement:

```
driver.findElement (new By.ByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'Your Login']")).click();
```

To this,

```
driver.findElement (AppiumBy.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'Your Login']")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks, it has worked out, thumbs up :)